# Unable to access Application Server with Port 9444

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I have change the carbon.xml, Offset 0 to 1

Server started with message:

```
[2017-08-03 11:51:56,169]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://IP:9444/carbon/
```

But I am not able to access to Application server with the URL above

Comment: Are ytou getting any errors? Do you see the message server started in x seconds message?

Comment: How does your browser look like when loading this page?

Comment: Thusitha, yes.
[2017-08-03 14:06:43,196]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 26 sec

Comment: Abimaran, the browser just show "The site can't be reached"

Comment: I can ping the ip. But failed when telnet the port.

Comment: It might be the IP problem. How to change the ip server in this line?
Mgt Console URL  : https://<IP>:9444/carbon/

Answer (score 0):

Issue have been resolved.

My LAN connection have blocked the port.